# Converting react/redux to use typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am converting an existing application to typescript. My application will not compile due to this error:

`Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttrributes<Component<{ dispatch: any; }`

Typescript adds the squiggly red line beneath the AddTodo component in App.tsx. I am very new to this and am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help.

App.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Footer from './Footer'
import AddTodo from '../containers/AddTodo'
import VisibleTodoList from '../containers/VisibleTodoList'

const App = () => (
  <div>
   <AddTodo />
   <VisibleTodoList />
  <Footer />
 </div>
 )

export default App
```

AddTodo.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo } from '../actions'

let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }: {dispatch: any}) => {
let input: any

return (
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      if (!input.value.trim()) {
        return
      }
      dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
      input.value = ''
    }}>
    <input ref={node => {
      input = node
    }} />
    <button type="submit">
      Add Todo
    </button>
    </form>
  </div>
  )
}

export default connect()(AddTodo)
```

Comment: `connect()(AddTodo)` creates a React component that requires property of type `IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttrributes<Component<{ dispatch: any; }`.
Since you pass nothing to it (`<AppTodo />`), it complains.

Comment: Maybe this needs to change then `let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }: {dispatch: any}) ` I pulled the existing app from the redux repository. Not sure If I'm doing this right.

Comment: That is ok. It about the `IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttrributes<Component<{ dispatch: any; }>>` requires some property to be filled in. There should be more error after the one you post. Can you post them?

Comment: `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttrributes<Component<{ dispatch: any; }, ComponentState>> & R...'. Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly< dispatch: any;}>'. Property 'dispatch' is missing in type '{}'.`

Comment: I would say a bug in the typings then. The `connect()` should hook up the `dispatch` function for you so that you don't have to do it manually. I've not worked on react-redux so I'm not sure. see if you can find your answer at react-redux or DefinitelyTyped depends on where the typings come from.